# Is it possible to get an 'object' from a PropertyInfo?

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

In my precent questions, I want to retrieve some values via reflection.
Now I want set values to objects thanks to reflection.

I want to write this :

```
private void AppliquerColonnesPersonnalisation(Control control, Propriete propriete, PropertyInfo Info)
        {
            UltraGrid grille = (UltraGrid)control;
            SortedList<int,string> sortedOrderedColumns = new SortedList<int,string>();

            if (grille != null)
            {
                // I want to write MapPropertyInfo method 
                ColumnsCollection cols = MapPropertyInfo(Info);
```

PropertyInfo contains a type of ColumnsCollection. I just want to "map" my PropertyInfo to an object to define some properties after : For example :

```
cols[prop.Nom].Hidden = false;
```

Is it possible ?

Best Regards,

Florian

EDIT : I tried the GenericTypeTea solution, but I have some problem. Here my code snippet :

```
        private void AppliquerColonnesPersonnalisation(Control control, Propriete propriete, PropertyInfo Info)
    {
        UltraGrid grille = (UltraGrid)control;
        ColumnsCollection c = grille.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns;

                    // Throw a not match System.Reflection.TargetException
        ColumnsCollection test = Info.GetValue(c,null) as ColumnsCollection;
        SortedList<int,string> sortedOrderedColumns = new SortedList<int,string>();
```

But a TargetException is Thrown

Comment: Can you show us the code where you get `Info`?

Answer (score 4):

So you already have a `PropertyInfo` object that is of type `ColumnsCollection`?

You can get it and modify it using the following code:

```
var original = GetYourObject();
PropertyInfo Info = GetYourPropertyInfo(original);
ColumnsCollection collection = Info.GetValue(original) as ColumnsCollection;
```

Basically, you just need to pass your original object back into the `PropertyInfo`'s GetValue method which will return you an object. Just cast that as the `ColumnsCollection` and you should be sorted.

**UPDATE:**

Based on your update, you should be doing this:

```
object original = grille.DisplayLayout.Bands[0];
PropertyInfo info = original.GetProperty("Columns");

ColumnsCollection test = info.GetValue(original, null) as ColumnsCollection;
```

You must be getting your `Info` `PropertyInfo` from an object of a different type. Although I think we're fixing the wrong problem here. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Why not just modify `grille.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns` directly?