# Is there a way to register events in bulk?

Tags: c#, events, reflection, properties, delegates

I have number of mother classes, each of these classes have different number of children objects of the same type. And the mother class need to register an event to all of these children objects.

Wondering if there's any good way to do the registration automatically?

Something like: go through all the properties inside the mother class, find properties of the children type, and register event.

Comment: "register an event to all of these children objects". It's not clear from this statement which way round the relationship is (who is the dispatcher and who is the receiver). Why not post some code to show us?

Comment: Isn't the Multicast nature of delegate suppose to do that . You subscribe lot of methods to the publisher? So if the mother class shares this delegate or event , all the children can subscribe to it.Maybe i haven't understood it correctly.

Comment: Make it more clear. it is unclear

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflections to subscribe to the events.

Define Child Class:

```
    class Child {
        public Child() { }            

        // Define event
        public event EventHandler DidSomethingNaughty;

        // Proeprty used to trigger event
        public bool IsNaughty {
            get { return this.isNaughty; }
            set {
                this.isNaughty = value;
                if (this.IsNaughty) {
                    if (this.DidSomethingNaughty != null) {
                        this.DidSomethingNaughty(this, new EventArgs());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Private data member for property
        private bool isNaughty = false;
    }
```

Define Mother Class:

```
    class Mother {

        public Mother() {
            this.subscribeToChildEvent();
        }

        // Properties
        public Child Child1 {
            get { return this.child1; }
            set { this.child1 = value; }
        }

        public Child Child2 {
            get { return this.child1; }
            set { this.child2 = value; }
        }

        public Child Child3 {
            get { return this.child3; }
            set { this.child3 = value; }
        }

        public Child Child4 {
            get { return this.child4; }
            set { this.child4 = value; }
        }

        // Private data members for the properties
        private Child child1 = new Child();
        private Child child2 = new Child();
        private Child child3 = new Child();
        private Child child4 = new Child();

        // This uses reflection to get the properties find those of type child
        // and subscribe to the DidSomethingNaughty event for each
        private void subscribeToChildEvent() {
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = 
                typeof(Mother).GetProperties();
            foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi in properties) {
                if (pi.ToString().StartsWith("Child")) {
                    Child child = pi.GetValue(this, null) as Child;
                    child.DidSomethingNaughty +=
                        new EventHandler(child_DidSomethingNaughty);
                }
            }
        }

        private void  child_DidSomethingNaughty(object sender, EventArgs e){
            Child child = (Child)sender;
            if (child.IsNaughty) {
                this.discipline(child);
            }
        }

        private void discipline(Child child) {                
            MessageBox.Show("Someone was naughty");
            // reset the flag so the next time the childe is
            //naughty the event will raise
            child.IsNaughty = false;
        }
    }
```

Then initialize a Mother object and it will subscript to the events:

```
    Mother m = new Mother();
```

Then set the IsNaughty property of Child1 to true:

```
    m.Child1.IsNaughty = true;
```

You should get a message box:

[image: You should get a message box:]

Resources:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/737156/1967692

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3179869/1967692